# VB.Net - 2 Classes with same Function Name resulting in same function - Argument not specified for parameter

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Log
        Public Shared Sub Log(p1 as integer, optional p2 as integer)
            Try

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub
End Class



Public Class ShortCutClass

        Public Shared Sub Log(p1 as integer)
            Try
                Log.Log(p1) '~~~~~~
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub

End Class



Argument not specified for parameter p1 of 'Public Shared Sub Log(p1 as integer)'
```

I have a Class called `Log`, with a Sub Called `Log`.

Sometimes in the website, `ShortCutClass.Log` is called - 
it is existing code and the only place I can make a change is within `ShortCutClass.Log`

There are many calls to both Log.Log and ShortCutClass.Log

I am getting the error `"Argument not specified for parameter p1 of 'Public Shared Sub Log(p1 as integer)'"`
It is like `Log.Log` tries to call itself, and then sees that it expects the parameter

How can I call `Log.Log` from

```
ShortCutClass.Log
```

Comment: `MyapplicationName.Log.Log(param)` fully qualified name.

Comment: I don't like the naming convention - confusing!

Comment: As you have found out. Having all those things called `Log` is confusing. How about changing the name of the `Log` class to something else such as `Logging`. Then `Logging.Log(p1)` should work.

Comment: I really want to, but its out of my control as it would affect a lot of pages...

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the fully qualified name of the application?

Comment: When you change the name of something you get the chance to rename all objects that belong to it. The easy way to get the fully qualified name is to type it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `Log.Log(p1)` you could type the namespace of the project.

Like this: `Namespace.Log.Log(p1)`  (Namespace could be the project name)

And the Optional Parameter should have a default value like this:

`Public Shared Sub Log(p1 as integer, Optional p2 as integer = 0)`

Comment: No namespaces unfortunately

Comment: There's a standard namespace. Try the project name as namespace.